# How to get the intersection of 2 lines in a plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to determine the intersection of two Matplotlib plots.
The input data for the first plot is stored in a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Time;Channel A;Channel B;Channel C;Channel D (s);(mV);(mV);(mV);(mV)
0,00000000;-16,28006000;2,31961900;13,29508000;-0,98889020
0,00010000;-16,28006000;1,37345900;12,59309000;-1,34293700
0,00020000;-16,16408000;1,49554400;12,47711000;-1,92894600
0,00030000;-17,10414000;1,25747800;28,77549000;-1,57489900
0,00040000;-16,98205000;1,72750600;6,73299900;0,54327920
0,00050000;-16,28006000;2,31961900;12,47711000;-0,51886220
0,00060000;-16,39604000;2,31961900;12,47711000;0,54327920
0,00070000;-16,39604000;2,19753400;12,00708000;-0,04883409
0,00080000;-17,33610000;7,74020200;16,57917000;-0,28079600
0,00090000;-16,98205000;2,31961900;9,66304500;1,48333500
```

This is the shortened CSV file. The Original has a lot more Data.
I got this code so far to get the FFT of Channel D:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
from numpy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq


a=pd.read_csv('20210629-0007.csv', sep = ';', skiprows=[1,2],usecols = [4],dtype=float, decimal=',')
dt = 1/10000
#print(a.head())

n=len(a)
     #time increment in each data

acc=a.values.flatten() #to convert DataFrame to 1D array
    #acc value must be in numpy array format for half way mirror calculation

fft=rfft(acc)*dt
freq=rfftfreq(n,d=dt)

FFT=abs(fft)


plt.plot(freq,FFT)
plt.axvline(x=150, color  = 'red')


plt.show()
```

Does anybody know how to get the intersection of those 2 plots ( red line and blue line at the same frequency ) ?

I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: I added a method to compute the intersection programmatically.  Can you update your question to add the comment that you initially put as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### manually

This is not really a programming question, rather basic mathematics.

Here is your plot:

[image: intersection of two lines]

Let's call (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) the first two points of your blue line and (x,y) the coordinates of the intersection.

You have this relationship between the points: `(x-x1)/(x2-x1) = (y-y1)/(y2-y1)`

Thus: `y=y1+(x-x1)*(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`

Which gives `FFT[0]+(150-0)*(FFT[1]-FFT[0])/(freq[1]-freq[0])`

Coordinates of the intersection are (150, 0.000189)

---

### programmatically

You can use the `pd.Series.interpolate` method

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,100,20),
              index=sorted(np.random.choice(range(100), 20))).sort_index()
ax = s.plot()
ax.axvline(35, color='r')

s.loc[35] = np.NaN
ax.plot(35, s.sort_index().interpolate(method='index').loc[35], marker='o')
```

[image: interpolation]